# problems with read in bash script

Tags: bash, while-loop

I am trying to read line by line from a serial port. The code below works, but I keep getting an error which I do not understand. Any clue?

That's the code

```
    while read line ; do
    if [ "$(line)"=='OFF' ] ;
      then
         echo "that was actually OFF"
    fi
    done < /dev/ttyACM0
```

That's the error:

```
   that was actually OFF 
   ./reading_loop.sh: line 9: line: command not found
```

Comment: $line or ${line} instead of $(line)

Comment: @Ronald why not post that as an answer?

Comment: @ssdecontrol: because it was so short. But you're right, it was actually an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if [ "$(line)"=='OFF' ] ;
```

1. `$(...)` executes the contents of the parentheses and returns the stdout. If you don't have a command named `line` you'll see a "command not found" error message, and `$()` will return an empty string.
2. `[...]` does different actions based on the number of arguments given. Since you only give a single word, the `[` command merely checks if the string is empty or not. In this case, `[` will see `""=='OFF'` which is not empty, therefore the success block will always be executed.